# How to Get Mouse Cursor Cordinates when left click is pressed and when left click is released in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, mouseevent, screenshot, sendinput

I am trying to create snipping tool for college project I am trying to work on: where user can take screenshot of area mouse covered and stretched while clicked.

For example : When left mouse is clicked : It gets cordinates x,y axis and when mouse is released it gets x,y axis. I cannot find any code or event function in SendInput() as well. Help.

For creating screenshot and adding into Clipboard I am using this code :

```
void screenshot(POINT a, POINT b)
{
    // copy screen to bitmap
    HDC     hScreen = GetDC(NULL);
    HDC     hDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hScreen);
    HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hScreen, abs(b.x - a.x), abs(b.y - a.y));
    HGDIOBJ old_obj = SelectObject(hDC, hBitmap);
    BOOL    bRet = BitBlt(hDC, 0, 0, abs(b.x - a.x), abs(b.y - a.y), hScreen, a.x, a.y, SRCCOPY);



    // save bitmap to clipboard
    OpenClipboard(NULL);
    EmptyClipboard();
    SetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP, hBitmap);
    CloseClipboard();

    // clean up
    SelectObject(hDC, old_obj);
    DeleteDC(hDC);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hScreen);
    DeleteObject(hBitmap);
}

int main()
{
    POINT a, b;
    a.x = 0;
    a.y = 0;

    b.x = 10000;
    b.y = 10000;

    screenshot(a, b);
}
```

Comment: That would depend on what GUI library/framework you are using.

Comment: I am using VS 2019.. Want to use windows library but if there are else available, please guide me

Comment: Qt would work cross platform. SFML or SDL are also cross platform options. Or you could use native Win32 and be locked to Windows. Other options also exist, but those 3 I have personal experience with and feel confident recommending.

Comment: `GetCursorPos`, you also want DPI compatibility

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Windows Desktop Application, not a console application, as in your case.Then, for your main Window you need to implement message handler for mouse, where you can handle mouse button clicks, and get position coordinates. Check for WTL samples.